# mysql_use_result stomping over used memory Ansi-C

Tags: mysql, c

i got a problem and its driving me nuts.

in a function called cargo_id_whitelist(MYSQL * conexion,struct info * data)

i perform a mysql Query. but every time i call the mysql api funcion
mysql_use_res(conexion) it stomp over used memory, ruining data (mostly of the data structure)

example

```
printf("-kind-> %d \n",conf_var->next->next->id) //work its display the third node id info;
res=( MYSQL_RES *)mysql_use_result(conexion); //this break my memory
printf("puntero %p \n",res);
printf("-kind-> %d \n",conf_var->next->next->id); //segfault
```

conf_var is a linked list.

theres is something i need to know?

Comment: Show how you got the connection you're passing in.

Comment: MYSQL *conn;
     if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, configuracion_db.servidor,
                            configuracion_db.usuariodb,
                            configuracion_db.passdb,
                            configuracion_db.nombre_db, 0, NULL, 0))     {
            return 1;
        }

Comment: used cast just for test, the normal code looks like     rsd=mysql_use_result(conexion)

Comment: dont get me wrong, i got data from mysql. but i need a data structure around to get some info. but the mysql_use_result keep stomping over my allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your comment, your code is as follows:

```
MYSQL *conn;
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, blah, blah, blah)) {
    return 1;
}
```

then you're breaking the rules and all bets are off. The [MySQL documentation page for `mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) states:

> The first parameter should be the address of an existing MYSQL structure. Before calling `mysql_real_connect()` you *must* call `mysql_init()` to initialize the MYSQL structure.

The statement `MYSQL *conn;` (assuming it's not static storage duration) simply creates a pointer that points to an *arbitrary* location and, unless you init it, using it is likely to cause you a great deal of grief.

The fix is probably simply replacing:

```
MYSQL *conn;
```

with:

```
MYSQL *conn = mysql_init (NULL);
```

That will give you a *new* object, properly initialised, that you can then pass to `mysql_real_connect()`.

Comment: in that case i already used mysql_init (NULL); this was some time ago and i already switched to pgsql without any troubles and also got better performance, the daemon is running since various months ago and there is no memory leaking. thanks you anyway.